# sum and group by on laravel relationship query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have this query below:

```
$consumptions = Consumption::with('consumption_item', 'consumption_item.item_stock', 'consumption_item.item_stock.invoice_item',
            'consumption_item.item_stock.invoice_item.measure_unit')
            ->whereIn('consumptions.ambulance_id', $subset)
            ->whereBetween('consumptions.document_date', [$old_from_date, $old_until_date])
            ->get();
```

What I am trying to do now is to perform a sum on consumption_items.quantity grouped by consumption_items.item_stock_id but I got no idea how can I make it without joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of functions related to eloquent collections (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) :

```
$grouped = $consumptions->groupBy('item_stock_id')->map(function ($row) {
                                  return $row->sum('quantity');
                                 });
```

The code reprocesses your data in ram memory, returning the values you need. You can also do it directly in a blade if you pass the `$consumptions` collection in the view.

Comment: hello! this doesn't work and I still couldn't find a solution..

Comment: Does the simple `$grouped = $consumptions->groupBy('item_stock_id');` query work? Is there any data? If that doesn't work, you have a problem with the previous query, otherwise you need to figure out which field to work on `map()`.